# Searching using SearchTern in javax.mail api is done in sever side or client side

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail

I want to know whether, email searching using SearchTerm is done in client side or server side, If we use :

```
Message[] message = folder.search(emailSearchTerm, Originalmessages);
```

where `Originalmessages` is array of messages.

Also if we use our own search term by extending SearchTerm class, then is searching done in client side or server side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Searching is done on the server for the standard search terms.  If you write your own search term, there's no way for the server to know what you're searching for, so searching is done on the client.

Comment: Thank you very much Bill Shannon. I am currently use SearchTerm similar to this

Comment: I am currently use my own search term by  extending SearchTerm class to carryout sub string matching (case insensitive) of 'from' address.  Then, it is done in client side even I carry out 'folder.search(mySearchTerm)'. is it right?

Comment: Yes, the search is going to be executed on the client.  Most mail servers will do case-independent searches of email addresses.  Did you try the standard FromTerm or FromStringTerm?